# Following code still works after error render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

I have a concern module as below

concerns/onboarding.rb

```
module Onboarding
  def status(onboard, params)
    if onboard.finished? && params[:process].present?
      render json: { error: 'You have already finished.'  }, status: :not_implemented
    end
  end
end
```

I am using it below

```
module MyAccount::User
  class OnboardingsController < ApplicationController
    include Onboarding
    def update
      status(current_kyc, params)
      current_kyc.update!(wizard_params)
    end

    private

    def current_kyc
      @wizard ||= current_user.onboardings.where(company_id: current_company.id).last
    end

    def wizard_params
      params.require(:onboarding).permit(:step, :finished)
    end
  end
end
```

This issue is, after `render json: { error: 'You have already finished.'  }, status: :not_implemented`, `current_kyc.update!(wizard_params)` is still executed. I don't know what the issue but `current_kyc.update!(wizard_params)` shouldn’t be implemented if `render json: { error: 'You have already finished.'  }, status: :not_implemented` is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `render` doesn't return or stop execution of a controller method. It only sets what should happen after the method call.

You can use [`performed?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-performed-3F) to check if the `render` method was already called, like this:

```
def update
  status(current_kyc, params)
  current_kyc.update!(wizard_params) unless performed?
end
```

But I am not really sure if this improves readability and makes it easier to understand what is actually going on in the controller.